# SQL trouble with multiple left joins and OR

Tags: mysql, sql-server, csv, join

I am trying to join an uploaded CSV (to MySQL0 to multiple other SQL tables and create output, but I am getting an issue where I see my data from the first table (the uploaded CSV) but it does not match up with the other tables (existing MySQL tables). I checked to make sure that the formats of the columns upon which I LEFT JOIN are the same. Is the problem that I am using an OR statement in the final JOIN, or could it be with that statement being rudimentary fuzzy logic.

```
$sql= "SELECT x.*, y.*, z.* FROM tbl_invoice as x LEFT JOIN conversion as y ON 
y.doc_sku = x.doc_sku LEFT JOIN tbl_catalog as z ON z.distributor_sku = COALESCE(y.dist_sku, x.doc_sku) OR x.item_name like '%z.item_description%' WHERE x.timestamp IN (SELECT MAX(timestamp) FROM tbl_invoice)";
    //echo $sql;die;
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $res = array();
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $res[] = $row;
        }
    }
    $html = "<table><tr><th>manufacturer</th><th>item_name</th><th>item_quantity</th><th>purchase_price</th><th>purchase_quantity</th><th>dist_sku</th><th>Total</th><th>item_description</th></tr>";
    foreach($res as $key=>$val)
    {
        $html .="<tr><td>".$val['manufacturer']."</td><td>".$val['item_name']."</td><td>".$val['item_quantity']."</td><td>".$val['purchase_price']."</td><td>".$val['purchase_quantity']."</td><td>".$val['dist_sku']."</td><td>".($val['purchase_price']-$val['price'])*$val['purchase_quantity']."</td><td>".$val['item_description']."</td></tr>";
    }
    $html .="</table>";
    echo $html;
    unlink($inputFileName);
    echo "<pre>";print_r($res);die;
} else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
}}?>
```

Comment: [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/) and [SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-reference) are different, unrelated software packages produced by different companies. Please use the correct tags.

Comment: @axiac couldn't say they're unrelated :p But that's just a troll comment!

Comment: @axiac Well, different certainly, but I couldn't call them unrelated

Answer (score 1):

Your join `like` statement isn't working as you expect it to. It's looking for a literal copy of the string `z.item_description`. Your query should be

```
SELECT 
  x.*
  , y.*
  , z.* 
FROM 
  tbl_invoice as x 
  LEFT JOIN conversion as y 
    ON y.doc_sku = x.doc_sku 
  LEFT JOIN tbl_catalog as z 
    ON z.distributor_sku    = COALESCE(y.dist_sku, x.doc_sku) 
    OR x.item_name       like concat('%', z.item_description, '%') 
WHERE 
  x.timestamp IN (
    SELECT 
      MAX(timestamp) 
    FROM 
      tbl_invoice
  )
```